Does FSC extend Sales/Service cloud?
Is it safe to say that Financial Services Cloud "extends" the functionality of Service or Sales Cloud?  I have a programming background and I actually look at this similar to how I look at object oriented design.  To me, it seems that Sales or Service Cloud is somewhat of a "base class" in which FSC "inherits from" to extend the functionality.  Is this an accurate analogy?
